# Print preview of specific iframe in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, activex

I have a page with multiple iframes. These frames have a print button attached to them that when clicked in chrome presents a nice print preview of that particular frame. In internet explorer a print dialog is presented without any preview.

The code run by the button is the following:

```
window.frames[frameName].print();
```

In order to present IE users with a print preview I've implemented the following function that gets called instead if a visitor is using IE:

```
function printPreview(frameDocument) {
    var browser = '<OBJECT ID="WebBrowser" WIDTH=0 HEIGHT=0 CLASSID="CLSID:8856F961-340A-11D0-A96B-00C04FD705A2"></OBJECT>';
    frameDocument.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', browser);    
    frameDocument.getElementById("WebBrowser").ExecWB(7, 1); // 7 = print preview, 1 = prompt user
    frameDocument.getElementById("WebBrowser").outerHTML = "";
}
```

This function creates the print preview but the content of the print preview is ***everything*** (including parent document and all other frames).

How can I make it so the print preview generated by `printPreview()` is only the specific frame and not the entire page?